# Get Parent Cell Reference / Transitive Property

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007

I'm having a problem where I need to reference the parent cell. So say A1's formula is "=B1", and B1's formula is "=C1". I need to compress A1's formula down to "=C1". I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in excel, or if there is a way to do this Apache POI. I have looked around, but can't really seem to find a solution to this. Does anyone know how to do this in excel or with the POI api?

Comment: In excel, you could start with selecting the cell and Going to the formula Tab and using "Trace Precedents", Or in Excel VBA you can use `Range("`*Your Range*`").Precedents`

Comment: That works, but it only seems to point to its parent. I probably should reword my question, I want to go up to the highest ancestor. So instead of A pointing to B, I want A to point to C because B depends on C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Sample running this would give you the results you asked for.

```
Sub GetLastPrecedent()

Dim pres As Range
Dim TestCell As Range

Set TestCell = Range("A1")
'Set pres to all cells that are used in getting the value of TestCell
'This includes all precedents of precedents
Set pres = TestCell.Precedents
'This will return the absolute precedent of the ones returned
Set pres = pres.Cells(pres.Rows.Count, pres.Columns.Count)
'This will set the formula in TestCell to use the absolute address
TestCell.Formula = "=" & pres.Address

End Sub
```

I hope this can at least help guide you to what you are looking for. More info will result in a better answer. Remember if you have complex formula that reference many cells this will become very dangerous and complicated. I only provide this sample based on the information given as a way to help guide you.